# dealing cards from a deck to an array of Cards called Hands

Tags: c#, targetinvocationexception

I am trying to deal 5 cards to a Hand object that can contain 6 card objects.
Ive written the hand class, the deck class and the card class.

The code deals cards to the Hand object which can contain Card objects, but i keep on getting the System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException in Presentation.dll exception.

```
//function to deal specified player the topmost cards from deck
//recieves an array of hands or Hand object
public void dealPlayerCardsFromDeck(Hand players, int numberOfCards )
{
    int j = 0;

    //loop to go through deck elements and to ensure the end of the player's hand isnt reached
    for (int i = 0; (i < deckLength) && (j <= numberOfCards); i++)
    {
       if (deck[i] != null)
       {
          players.hands[j].face = deck[i].face;
          players.hands[j].value = deck[i].value;
          deck[i] = null;
          j++;
       }
    }
}//end function
```

Here is the code that calls it in Main()

```
cardDeck.dealPlayerCardsFromDeck(players[0],5);
```

the "cardDeck" is an object of Class Deck

```
Deck cardDeck = new Deck();
```

Please note I am using c#

Answer (score 0):

I think the most logical explanation is some sort of index out or range issue in the loop when indexing the arrays using  i or j.
I recommend following the execution in a debugger to see if i or j is incremented past the size of the arrays

Comment: I did do that, the exception occurs at "players.hands[j].face = deck[i].face;" before i or j gets incremented